# How to add a row dynamically into form in thymeleaf, without submitting data to controller?

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am creating a dynamic form using thymeleaf and spring. My requirement is same like that in this [link](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/thymeleafspring.html) (section 9). Example: When I click add row button in Rows section a new row should get added below Rows section. This approach is working fine without any issues. In this approach whenever i click add row Controller method will get invoked and form is submitted and complete page is refreshed for every add row click action.

But in my case i have a big form where it will have multiple rows like this. So my doubt is how can i add a row into form element which was developed using thymeleaf, without posting the form to controller and creating a new object in controller and refreshing the complete page again. Is there any way to do this using ajax and jquery. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript to add rows to a table dynamically.
For taking that whole data to your controller you can use List of data that you are sending. Javascript allow to change the attribute name dynamically.On controller side you just need to fetch that list and use in your code.